# eclipse maven dependencies pom file

Tags: eclipse, maven

Hi does anybody know where do i need to setup the mahout.version property in order for eclipse to get the latest version of the dependency?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
    <version>${mahout.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a super pom or parent pom.xml you can make the properties like this :

```
<properties>
<mahout.version>0.9</mahout.version>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace following in your pom.xml of maven build.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
    <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.8</version>
</dependency>
```